# How can I improve this question on how to see the commit size for each loaded DLL in Microsoft Windows 7?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I was told to  improve this question: https://superuser.com/q/1681006/116475

I don't know what to add to it. Suggestions?

---

The question was removed by Roomba. The question was:

> I read [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1680921/116475) by [Frédéric Loyer](https://superuser.com/users/1563953/fr%c3%a9d%c3%a9ric-loyer):
>
> > We should take into account the shared pages. Typically all loaded DLL are shared and this makes impossible to just sum the commit size of each process and expect it to match the commit size of the whole system.
>
> How can one see the commit size for each loaded DLL in Microsoft Windows 7?

Comment: I'm assuming, since you are posting here, that you are still interested in any answers to the question, even a year later, right?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thanks, yes, still interested.

Answer (score 2):

That's a bit of a weird one.  I see @JourneymanGeek undeleted it, but then it was Roomba'd again.  I'd be happy to upvote it, personally, if it got reopened (and you let me know before it gets undeleted), but I think it would require one additional upvote to prevent another deletion.

> I don't know what to add to it. Suggestions?

I don't see that the question needs any additional information, myself.  You are clear about the original problem (which you linked) that you were trying to resolve, along with the this being information you needed for the "next step" based on the answer to the previous question.

And it's not that it was Closed, of course.  The [vote history](https://superuser.com/review/close/1152819) shows that it received no Close votes and two "Leave Open" votes, so maybe the Close vote was retracted.

Just that the one downvote eventually caused it to Roomba (twice).  We don't, of course, even know why the downvote is there from the original posting.

I think you were correct to post a new question, since the old one had been answered, but you needed *additional* details on how to perform the actions recommended.

Another avenue *could* have been to edit your original question, but that would have changed its scope, which I'd disagree with.